# ValidationError: RFDeviceId: Path `RFDeviceId` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new here and know only baiscs of nodejs and mongodb so please help me to learn.

I'm getting this error

Error creating the dataset: ValidationError: RFDeviceId: Path `RFDeviceId` is required., coordinates: Path `coordinates` is required., CoordinatesTime: Path `CoordinatesTime` is required., speed: Path `speed` is required., sat_tracked: Path `sat_tracked` is required., gps_fix_type: Path `gps_fix_type` is required., temperatureata: Path `temperatureata` is required., humidity: Path `humidity` is required., bat_v: Path `bat_v` is required., bat_p: Path `bat_p` is required.

and my datasets.js in model is like that

````
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Declare schema
var datasetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner_name: {type: String, required: true},
    RFDeviceId: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
    coordinates: {type: Number, required: true},
    CoordinatesTime: {type: String, required: true},
    speed: {type: String, required: true},
    sat_tracked: {type: Number, required: true},
    gps_fix_type: {type: Number, required: true},
    temperatureata: {type: Number, required: true},
    humidity: {type: Number, required: true}, 
    bat_v: {type: Number, required: true},
    bat_p: {type: Number, required: true}
});

// Export schema
mongoose.model("Dataset", datasetSchema);```
````

and my datasets.js in routes

```
/* CRUD API */
// POST new dataset request
router.post("/", helper.authenticate, function(req, res) {
    // Used to set the dataset owner
    var sessionUser = req.session.user.name;
    // Get values from the post request
    var RFDeviceId = req.body.RFDeviceId;
    var coordinates = req.body.coordinates;
    var CoordinatesTime = req.body.CoordinatesTime;
    var speed = req.body.speed;
    var sat_tracked = req.body.sat_tracked;
    var gps_fix_type = req.body.gps_fix_type;
    var temperatureata = req.body.temperatureata;
    var humidity = req.body.humidity;
    var bat_v = req.body.bat_v;
    var bat_p = req.body.bat_p;
    // Delete the values from the request body so that we only keep information about the variables
    delete req.body.RFDeviceId;
    delete req.body.coordinates;
    delete req.body.CoordinatesTime;
    delete req.body.speed;
    delete req.body.sat_tracked;
    delete req.body.gps_fix_type;
    delete req.body.temperatureata;
    delete req.body.humidity;
    delete req.body.bat_v;
    delete req.body.bat_p;
    `

    // This is so that we can loop through the object in reverse order
    // We do that so that the fields are saved in the right order on the db
    // (this way it will appear in the right order on the 'edit' view)
    var propertiesList = [];
    for (var property in req.body) {
        if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            propertiesList.push(property);
        }
    }
    propertiesList.reverse();

    var variablesFields = {};
    for (var i in propertiesList) {
        console.log(propertiesList[i])
        variablesFields[propertiesList[i]] = {name:req.body[propertiesList[i]],
                                    values: Array}; 
    }

    // Create dataset 
    Dataset.create({
        RFDeviceId: RFDeviceId,
        coordinates: coordinates, 
        CoordinatesTime: CoordinatesTime,
        speed: speed,
        sat_tracked: sat_tracked,
        gps_fix_type: gps_fix_type,
        temperatureata: temperatureata,
        humidity: humidity,
        bat_v: bat_v,
        bat_p: bat_p,
        owner_name: sessionUser
    }, function(err, dataset) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error creating the dataset: " + err);
            req.session.error = "A problem occured when creating the dataset. Please try again.";
        } else {
            console.log("New dataset created with id: " + dataset._id);
            req.session.success = "Dataset " + "name" + " created successfully.";
        }
        res.redirect("/index");
    });
});

// PUT request to update dataset
router.put("/:id/", helper.authenticate, function(req, res) {
    // Get values from the POST request
    var RFDeviceId = req.body.RFDeviceId;
    var coordinates = req.body.coordinates;
    var CoordinatesTime = req.body.CoordinatesTime;
    var speed = req.body.speed;
    var sat_tracked = req.body.sat_tracked;
    var gps_fix_type = req.body.gps_fix_type;
    var temperatureata = req.body.temperatureata;
    var humidity = req.body.humidity;
    var bat_v = req.body.bat_v;
    var bat_p = req.body.bat_p;
    // Delete the values from the request body so that we only keep information about the variables
    delete req.body.RFDeviceId;
    delete req.body.coordinates;
    delete req.body.CoordinatesTime;
    delete req.body.speed;
    delete req.body.sat_tracked;
    delete req.body.gps_fix_type;
    delete req.body.temperatureata;
    delete req.body.humidity;
    delete req.body.bat_v;
    delete req.body.bat_p;

    var setList = {};
    var unsetList = {};
    var updateQuery = {};

    // Find dataset by id
    Dataset.findById(req.params.id, function(err, dataset) {
        updateQuery = {
            RFDeviceId: RFDeviceId,
            coordinates: coordinates, 
            CoordinatesTime: CoordinatesTime,
            speed: speed,
            sat_tracked: sat_tracked,
            gps_fix_type: gps_fix_type,
            temperatureata: temperatureata,
            humidity: humidity,
            bat_v: bat_v,
            bat_p: bat_p,
        }
        // If variable in request body and not in dataset, add to setList (or if no variable at all in dataset)
        for (var property in req.body) {
            if (!dataset.data||(req.body.hasOwnProperty(property)&!dataset.data.hasOwnProperty(property))) {
                console.log(property)
                console.log(req.body[property])
                setList["data."+ property] = {name:req.body[property],
                                                values: Array}; 
            }
        }

        // If variable in dataset but not in request body, add to unsetList
        for (var property in dataset.data) {
            if (dataset.data&&dataset.data.hasOwnProperty(property)&!req.body.hasOwnProperty(property))
            {
                unsetList["data."+property] = true;
            }
        }

        // If setList or unsetList non-empty, add to updateQuery
        if (Object.keys(setList).length) {
            updateQuery["$set"] = setList;
        }
        if (Object.keys(unsetList).length) {
            updateQuery["$unset"] = unsetList;
        }

        // Update dataset
        dataset.update(updateQuery, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error updating dataset: " + err);
                req.session.error = "Update failed, please try again.";
            } else {
                console.log("Update on dataset: " + dataset._id);
                req.session.success = "Update successul.";
            }
            res.redirect("/index");
        });
    });
});
```

if I set required: false expect with owner_name then first data send time it send `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.datasets index: index_1 dup key: { : null }`

output screenshot https://ibb.co/pyVXD01

Please help it great pleasure to all.

Comment: Hi, can you explain by giving a sample document, and the expected output?

Comment: Please update your question with that info

Comment: can you please help me to where I'm doing mistake. It's my great pleasure @SuleymanSah

Answer (score 0):

As you make all the fields required in your model. So whenever you make any dataset, you need to give all your required field's data.

And in your create dataset query API, you first directly assign req.body.[filed-value] to a new variable which also copy the reference of that origin variable.

And when you delete the original variable, your copied variable also lost their values and set to undefined.[read ES Documentation](http://es6-features.org)
Now your Create query looks like :

```
// POST new dataset request
router.post("/", helper.authenticate, function(req, res) {
    // Used to set the dataset owner
    var sessionUser = req.session.user.name;
    // Get values from the post request
    var RFDeviceId = req.body.RFDeviceId;
    var coordinates = req.body.coordinates;
    var CoordinatesTime = req.body.CoordinatesTime;
    var speed = req.body.speed;
    var sat_tracked = req.body.sat_tracked;
    var gps_fix_type = req.body.gps_fix_type;
    var temperatureata = req.body.temperatureata;
    var humidity = req.body.humidity;
    var bat_v = req.body.bat_v;
    var bat_p = req.body.bat_p;

    // This is so that we can loop through the object in reverse order
    // We do that so that the fields are saved in the right order on the db
    // (this way it will appear in the right order on the 'edit' view)
    var propertiesList = [];
    for (var property in req.body) {
        if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            propertiesList.push(property);
        }
    }
    propertiesList.reverse();

    var variablesFields = {};
    for (var i in propertiesList) {
        console.log(propertiesList[i])
        variablesFields[propertiesList[i]] = {name:req.body[propertiesList[i]],
                                    values: Array}; 
    }

    // Create dataset 
    Dataset.create({
        RFDeviceId: RFDeviceId,
        coordinates: coordinates, 
        CoordinatesTime: CoordinatesTime,
        speed: speed,
        sat_tracked: sat_tracked,
        gps_fix_type: gps_fix_type,
        temperatureata: temperatureata,
        humidity: humidity,
        bat_v: bat_v,
        bat_p: bat_p,
        owner_name: sessionUser
    }, function(err, dataset) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error creating the dataset: " + err);
            req.session.error = "A problem occured when creating the dataset. Please try again.";
        } else {
            console.log("New dataset created with id: " + dataset._id);
            req.session.success = "Dataset " + "name" + " created successfully.";
        }
        res.redirect("/index");
    });
});
```

I hope you got the idea of doing it correctly.

[DO VOTE TO THIS ANSWER, IF ITS HELPFUL TO YOU]

Comment: I appreciate you answer my question but I already check this situation and error is same.if you have any better idea then please help.